# Is this database design proper for storing the survey results?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

In my company, we asked all some departments employees to participate in a survey. The structure of this survey is as following: it consists of four categories; I, II, III, IV. Three categories have couple of questions, while the last category has subcategories from A to L. Each Subcategory has many questions. And most of these questions have subquestions.

There are two kinds of questions; multiple choice questions with different number of choices (sometimes 2 or 4 or 5 or 6 choices) and written question (such as please comment on the following stuff...). An example of a question that has subquestions:
What do you think about the following services?
Service 1
Service 2
Service 3

By the way, this question is a multiple choice question where each subquestions (such as service1) has 5 choices.

**The problem now** is just creating a database that stores the user information, the questions, and the user answers. The purpose of this database to come up with statistics later on based on the question. For instance, I have to write a query that shows how many employees said (Agree or Strongly Disagree) on Question #3 with showing the subquestions, too.

I came up with following incomplete database design, but it seems to be complicated:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, DepartmentID
Department Table: DepartmentID, DepartmentName
Category Table: CategoryID, CategoryName
SubCategory Table: SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName, CategoryID
Question Table: QuestionID, Question
SubQuestion Table: SubQuestionID, SubQuestion, QuestionID
Answer Table: AnswerID, Answer, QuestionID, SubQuestionID
```

So what is the best database design that can stores all of this information and then gives me the general statistics that I want?

Comment: I'd add Id on Employee table even if user name is a good candidate for primary key. And if you have list of choices, then may be something like Choices (ChoiceId, QuestionId, Text) and link answer directly to choice for appropriate type of questions. It would be much easier to analyze later.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion will be something like this:

```
Employee Table: UserId, Username, Name, DepartmentId
Department Table: DepartmentId, DepartmentName
Category Table: CategoryId, CategoryName, ParentId

Question Table: QuestionId, Question, CategoryId
QuestionChoices Table: ChoiceId, QuestionId, Choice, Sequence

Answer Table: AnswerId, QuestionId, UserId, Text
AnswerChoices Table: AnswerId, QuestionId, UserId, ChoiceId, [Value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee & Department tables look fine. I have the following suggestions:

-- Include Sub-, Category, Sub- & Question numbers in their respective tables (i.e.: I, II, III, IV for Category, A, B, C etc for questions and so on, assuming Question/CategoryName is the full-length Question/Category)

-- QuestionID table should include a SubCategoryID FK.

-- I would also have an employeeID as suggested in comments (usernames may be reused after people leave).

-- Then I'd design the following tables:

```
Answer Table:

AnswerID
SubquestionID
AnswerType (choose between 'Multiple', 'Long')
AnswerName (NULL if AnswerType is 'Long', a, b, c, etc if 'Multiple')

SurveyResults Table: 

EmpID (FK from Employee table),
SubQuestionID (a, b, c, ...; again if no subquestion, then put in a)
Answer (varchar(4000), so you can accommodate both types of answers)
```

Note that you should keep an Answer table to hold the choices for the multiple choice questions.

Comment: I find myself editing and re-editing my answer as I think this through. The thing is: you need to decide whether you want to update responses quickly or analyse results quickly. My suggestion above is for the former case. For the latter case, after the survey has been closed, I would create a table from a view on the existing tables that shows EmpID, CategoryNum, SubCatNum, QuestionNum, SubQuestionNum, AnswerType, Answer. This new table would then be a good basis for further analysis.